# How do I, Can I turn off grant hierarchies for the Case object?

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy

We wish to not allow access to Cases marked as "Sensitive" to People in Roles above the owner of the case in the Role Hierarchy.

e.g. Bob is trained on sensitive data, and his Manager Sue is not, so only Bob and the sensitive Group of users can see this sensitive Case.

**When trying to turn off Grant Access Using Hierarchies for the Case object, it is greyed out.**

**Can we, How can we turn this off?**

This question is not to answer the XY problem of how to restrict access.
It is asking:
**"Can we turn off Grant Access Using Hierarchies on the Case object or other Standard Objects that are greyed out"**

Keywords: Account, Contact, Opportunity, Lead

I realise this is an XY Problem so I write this for the purpose of Google search, and for the very direct answer that will come.

[image]

Comment: You cant change grant access using hierarchy for standard objects, top of my mind I am thinking for your scenario may be you can remove roles from users

Comment: not really an option to remove roles, this would create more problems.

Comment: Your answer is correct if you want to post it. The answer is "No you cannot." Or so I believe.

Comment: the answer to my XY problem (the actual problem) is to create a more segregated Role Structure with Roles specifically for Sensitive Cases, at each level of the hierarchy, including managers managers.

Comment: I think yes this should resolve your issues keeping role hierarchy for sensitive group separate and only head of the tree would be common that would your cfo and ceo etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deselect the grant access using hierachy for standard objects , it can be modified only for custom objects.

> The Grant Access Using Hierarchies is enabled for most standard objects, but not all of them. You can modify this option for custom objects by deselecting it.

Below is snap from salesforce document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks elijah.
Nice One!

Comment: Nice answer, but you should avoid using an image when text would suffice. Screen readers and other accessibility tools can't "read" images this way, which may hinder some people's ability to read the text.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Mr. Fox, updating answer to add same text as well.